# Create a simple automatic image switcher using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, carousel

I need to create a very simple image switcher that changes my images automatically. I have the following code:

```
<div class="imgCarousel">
   <div class="imgC1 left"><img src="/media/1614/1_1.jpg" alt="img1" /></div>
   <div class="imgC2 left"><img src="/media/1615/2_1.jpg" alt="img2" /></div>
   <div class="imgC3 left"><img src="/media/1616/3_1.gif" alt="img3" /></div>
   <div class="imgC4 left"><img src="/media/1617/4_1.jpg" alt="img4" /></div>
   <div class="imgC5 left"><img src="/media/1618/5_1.jpg" alt="img5a" /></div>
   <div class="imgC6 left"><img src="/media/1620/6_1.jpg" alt="img6a" /></div>
   <div class="imgC7 left"><img src="/media/1622/7.jpg" alt="img7" /></div>
</div>
```

Two of the above images should be switched automatically after a certain amount of time (every 3-4 sec.).
This means that after 4 seconds, I'd like to change the image called **/media/1618/5_1.jpg** with another image. And after another 4 seconds, I'd switch back again. The same shold be made for one of my other images. How can I acomplish this with some jQuery?

Comment: There are SO many plugins that will do this for you, with fancy transitions between images. Is there a specific reason you want to code it yourself?

Comment: As a side note, you have a lot of superfluous markup in your code. You won't need to wrap the images in divs for a start. Also I'm assuming the "left" class floats the images left? why not apply the rules to .imgCarousel img instead? And do you need a unique class on each image? This is not what classes are for, if you need an identifier use "id" instead, but most likely you don't need it anyway. A more semantic way of writing it might be to use and unordered list (UL) instead. 
With regard to the question tho, I agree with Bernhard, just find a plugin to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I won't code it for you... and there are so many ways to kill a dog...

give this links or jQuery methods a read...

- [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)
- [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)
- [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

get some code started, then come back when have problem with the codes...

Answer (score 1):

Using your code as a reference, you could just use a setInterval that shows/hides the divs you want. However, there are dozens of different ways to do it.

The setInterval would be:

```
var loop = setInterval("nextImage()",1000);
```

Then nextImage() would show/hide the images, I'll use jQuery as an example:

```
var index = 0;
var images_size = $(".imgCarousel div").size();

function nextImage(){
// we hide all the divs and show the next one only
$(".imgCarousel div").hide();
$(".imgCarousel div").eq(index).show();
// we continue the iteration
index = index+1;
if(index >= images_size){ index = 0; }
}
```

This is a quick and dirty improvisation as an example but, again, there are lots of ways of doing it.
You might want to check functions like `load()`, `src()` for preloads, and others like `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`... for smooth transition/effects.